# Random android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE error on receiving calls

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I need some help,I did search many times for this problem I have but didn't find solution,
my problem is about recording receiving calls;getting me random force close (not all time)

here is complete full my services

```
    public class BiftorCallRecorderService extends Service
{
        MediaRecorder recorder=new MediaRecorder();
        boolean recording=false;
        String CallNumber;
        Boolean DEBUG=false;
        Context mContext;
        int AudioRecordSource;
        int AudioOutFormat;
        String OutFormat;
        public static String OutFile;
        String OutFileTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        Boolean ShowNotification;
        Boolean EnableCallRecording ,RecordMyNumbersOnly;

        //All About DropBox
        final static private String ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
        final static private String ACCESS_KEY_NAME = "ACCESS_KEY";
        final static private String ACCESS_SECRET_NAME = "ACCESS_SECRET";
        final static private String APP_KEY = "wyhim4z3oa3gbb8";
        final static private String APP_SECRET = "cnfg4zr2ifrq200";
        static DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mApi;        

        /**
         * calling BiftorSettings for set settings
         * detect phone state  
         * if record my number only was enable go to find method and check the number if contain 
         * that number start recording if not dont start
         * if the phone state is idle stop recording meaning if call end
         */ 
        BroadcastReceiver CallRecorder=new BroadcastReceiver()
            {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent)
                {
                    BiftorSettings();
                    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state))
                    {
                        File Numbers_File = new File("data/data/com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities/files/Record_Number.txt");
                        String number=CallNumber.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                        if(find(Numbers_File, number) && RecordMyNumbersOnly&&recorder!=null)
                            BiftorStartRecording();
                        else if(!RecordMyNumbersOnly&&recorder!=null)
                            BiftorStartRecording();
                        }

                     if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state))
                         {
                            BiftorStopRecording();
                         }
                        if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state))
                            {
                             CallNumber=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                            }
                }
            };

            /**
             * getting Receive Phone number and save in  
             * CallNumber string
             */  
            BroadcastReceiver OutGoingNumDetector=new BroadcastReceiver()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
                        {
                            BiftorSettings();
                            CallNumber=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                        }
                };

        /**
        * creat service and register recivers
        * call the BiftorSettings
        */                
        @Override
        public void onCreate()
            {
                super.onCreate();               
                IntentFilter RecFilter = new IntentFilter();
                RecFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
                registerReceiver(CallRecorder, RecFilter);
                IntentFilter OutGoingNumFilter=new IntentFilter();
                OutGoingNumFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
                registerReceiver(OutGoingNumDetector, OutGoingNumFilter);
                BiftorSettings();
                }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
        {
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
        {
            return null;
        }

    /**
     * destory Receivers
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(CallRecorder);
        unregisterReceiver(OutGoingNumDetector);
    }



    /**
     * starting recording
     * if EnableCallRecording not true get out from this method
     * settings recorder.setAudioSource(AudioRecordSource) from BiftorSettings
     * settings output format from BiftorSettings
     * make out dir from BiftorSettings
     * recorder.prepare() and set the recording state true
     * if recorder cant start put  recorder = null the user should select other recording Audio source
     * if recorder.start working fine set Isrecording=true else if recorder.start not wrok have problems 
     * set the Isrecording=false recording=false and set the recorder null
     * if Isrecording=true send notification and show toast start recording else recording failed
     */
    public void BiftorStartRecording()
    {

    if(!EnableCallRecording)return;

    if(recording==false)
        {
        Boolean Isrecording;
   try {
        recorder.setAudioSource(AudioRecordSource);   
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4); 
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        OutFile= prefs.getString("Biftor_Recorder_Utilities_Dir_Picker", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/BiftorRecorder")+"/BiftorCallRecorder";

        File dir= new File(OutFile);
        if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();

        switch (AudioOutFormat) {
        case 1:
            OutFormat = ".3gp";
            break;
        case 2:
            OutFormat = ".mpg";
            break;
        case 3:
            OutFormat = ".amr";
            break;
        case 4:
            OutFormat = ".wav"; 
            break;
        case 5:
            OutFormat = ".mp3";                 
            break;
        }

        OutFile+="/"+CallNumber+ "_" + OutFileTime+ OutFormat;
        recorder.setOutputFile(OutFile);

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
            recording=true;
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            recorder = null;
            return;
        }

        recorder.start();
        Isrecording=true;

    } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        recording=false;
        Isrecording=false;
        recorder = null;
    }
   if(Isrecording){
    if(ShowNotification)
        SendNotification(true);
    else
        SendNotification(false);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.BiftorCallRecorder_Sarted) +CallNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }else
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.Recording) +getString(R.string.failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


  }   
}      

    /**
     * Stop Recording and check out file method
     * and remove Notification
     * and send the BroadcastIntent
     * if recording have problem recording is false and put the recorder empty
     * relase,rest and stop the recorder at last put to null if recording is true
     * if EnableCallRecording is not true get out from this method
     */
    public void BiftorStopRecording()
    {
    if(!EnableCallRecording)return;

        if(recording==true)
            {
            if(recorder!=null){ //add this check
               recorder.stop();
               recorder.reset();
               recorder.release();
               recorder=null;
            } //add this closing bracket too
            recording=false;
            SendBroadcastIntent();
            SendNotification(false);
            CheckOutPutFile(OutFile);
          } else {
              recorder=null;
              recording=false;
              SendNotification(false);
              CheckOutPutFile(OutFile);
          } 
          //prepare a new recorder for next call
          recorder =new MediaRecorder();  
    }

    /**
     * Restart this service after end
     */
    public void SendBroadcastIntent()
        {
           Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.setAction("com.Biftor.BiftorCallRecorder.CALRECORDER_INTENT");
           sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

    /**
     * check output file if not having zero size save that
     */   
    public void CheckOutPutFile(String outfile)
    {
    File outputfile=new File(outfile);
    if (outputfile.exists()){
        if(outputfile.length()<=0){
            outputfile.delete();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.BiftorCallRecorder_Status)+" :"+
            getString(R.string.Recording)+" "+
            getString(R.string.is_empty), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.Record_Saved)+ OutFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            if(prefs.getBoolean("Biftor_DropBox_Upload_CallRecords", false)&isNetworkAvailable())
            BiftorUploadToDropBox(OutFile);
        }
    }else
        return;
    }

    /**
     * check number is in blacklist
     */
    public boolean find(File f, String searchString) {
        boolean result = false;
        Scanner in = null;
        if(f.exists())
        {
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new FileReader(f));
            while(in.hasNextLine() && !result) {
                result = in.nextLine().indexOf(searchString) >= 0;
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();      
        }
        finally {
            try { in.close() ; } catch(Exception e) { /* ignore */ }  
        }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Recording Settings
     */
    public void BiftorSettings() {
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        AudioRecordSource = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("Biftor_Audio_Record_Source", "1"));
        AudioOutFormat = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("Biftor_Audio_Out_Format", "1"));
        ShowNotification = prefs.getBoolean("Biftor_Show_Notification", true);
        EnableCallRecording = prefs.getBoolean("Biftor_Enable_Call_Recording", true);
        RecordMyNumbersOnly = prefs.getBoolean("Biftor_Enable_Record_My_Numbers_Only", false);
    }


    /**
     * send ther recording state notification
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void SendNotification(Boolean status)
    {
        Context c = getApplicationContext();
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        if (status) {
            int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, getString(R.string.Recording)+CallNumber+getString(R.string.call), System.currentTimeMillis());
            CharSequence contentTitle = getString(R.string.BiftorCallRecorder_Status);
            CharSequence contentText = getString(R.string.Recording) +CallNumber+getString(R.string.call);
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, BiftorCallRecorderSettings.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(c, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);            
        } else {
            mNotificationManager.cancel(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Upload Recorders to user dropbox after end
     */
    public void BiftorUploadToDropBox(String outFile) {
        AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
        mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        File file=new File(outFile);
        if(file.exists()){
        String Dropboxfolder ="/"+prefs.getString("DropBox_User_CallRecorder_Folder", "")+"/";
        BiftorAutoUploadCallsToDropbox upload = new BiftorAutoUploadCallsToDropbox(getApplicationContext(), mApi, Dropboxfolder, file);
        upload.execute();
        }
        else 
            return;
        }

    /**
    * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a local
    * store, rather than storing user name & password, and re-authenticating each
    * time (which is not to be done, ever).
    */
    public void loadAuth(AndroidAuthSession session) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, null);
        String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, null);
        if (key == null || secret == null || key.length() == 0 || secret.length() == 0) return;

        if (key.equals("oauth2:")) {
            // If the key is set to "oauth2:", then we can assume the token is for OAuth 2.
            session.setOAuth2AccessToken(secret);
        } else {
            // Still support using old OAuth 1 tokens.
            session.setAccessTokenPair(new AccessTokenPair(key, secret));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Upload Recorders to user dropbox after end
     */
    public AndroidAuthSession buildSession() {
        AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair);
        loadAuth(session);
        return session;
    }   

    /**
     * check the network 
     */
    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
              = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    }
```

here is receiver

```
public class BiftorCallRecorderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                arg0.stopService(new Intent(arg0,BiftorCallRecorderService.class));
                Intent intent=new Intent(arg0, BiftorCallRecorderService.class);
                arg0.startService(intent);
             //   Toast.makeText(arg0, "Service BroadcastReceiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    }
```

here is manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <service
        android:name="com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities.BiftorCallRecorder.BiftorCallRecorderService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.Biftor.BiftorCallRecorder.CALRECORDER_INTENT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities.BiftorCallRecorder.BiftorCallRecorderReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.Biftor.BiftorCallRecorder.CALRECORDER_INTENT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

at last here is my logcat

```
W/BroadcastQueue(18654): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x10 (has extras) } from android (pid=19243, uid=1001) is not exported from uid 10057 due to receiver com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities/.BiftorCallRecorder.BiftorCallRecorderReceiver

E/AndroidRuntime(20713): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(20713): Process: com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities, PID: 20713

E/AndroidRuntime(20713): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities.BiftorCallRecorder.BiftorCallRecorderService$1@41db6990

E/AndroidRuntime(20713):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:769)

E/AndroidRuntime(20713):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

E/AndroidRuntime(20713):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

E/AndroidRuntime(20713):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

E/AndroidRuntime(20713):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5043)

E/AndroidRuntime(20713):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(20713):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

E/AndroidRuntime(20713):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)

E/AndroidRuntime(20713):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)

E/AndroidRuntime(20713):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(20713): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(20713):    at com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities.BiftorCallRecorder.BiftorCallRecorderService.BiftorStopRecording(BiftorCallRecorderService.java:282)

E/AndroidRuntime(20713):    at com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities.BiftorCallRecorder.BiftorCallRecorderService$1.onReceive(BiftorCallRecorderService.java:90)

E/AndroidRuntime(20713):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:759)

E/AndroidRuntime(20713):    ... 9 more

I/ActivityManager(18654): Process com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities (pid 20713) has died.

W/ActivityManager(18654): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities/.BiftorCallRecorder.BiftorCallRecorderService in 1000ms

I/ActivityManager(18654): Start proc com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities for service com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities/.BiftorCallRecorder.BiftorCallRecorderService: pid=21531 uid=10057 gids={50057, 1028, 1015, 1023, 3003}
```

please don't get this question negative rate I added all things need:-)
sorry for bad English.

**Edit**

**code cleaned and add comment for each method hope this time is better**

**Edit2 but error again**

```
    public class BiftorCallRecorderService extends Service
{
  MediaRecorder recorder=new MediaRecorder();
  boolean recording=false;
  String CallNumber;
  Context mContext;
  String OutFormat;
  public static String OutFile;
  String OutFileTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

   /**
   * detect phone state  
   * if the phone state is idle stop recording meaning if call end
   */ 
   BroadcastReceiver CallRecorder=new BroadcastReceiver()
       {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent)
          {
           String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
           if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state)&&recorder!=null)
                  {
                     BiftorStartRecording();
                   }
           if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state))
                   {
                     BiftorStopRecording();
                   }
            if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state))
                    {
                      CallNumber=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    }
           }
        };

     /**
     * getting Receive Phone number and save in  
     * CallNumber string
     */  
     BroadcastReceiver OutGoingNumDetector=new BroadcastReceiver()
          {
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
             {
               CallNumber=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
             }
          };

    /**
    * creat service and register recivers
    */                
   @Override
   public void onCreate()
       {
          super.onCreate();             
          IntentFilter RecFilter = new IntentFilter();
          RecFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
          registerReceiver(CallRecorder, RecFilter);
          IntentFilter OutGoingNumFilter=new IntentFilter();
          OutGoingNumFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
          registerReceiver(OutGoingNumDetector, OutGoingNumFilter);
        }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
        {
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
        {
            return null;
        }

    /**
     * destory Receivers
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(CallRecorder);
        unregisterReceiver(OutGoingNumDetector);
    }

    /**
     * starting recording
     * if EnableCallRecording not true get out from this method
     * settings recorder.setAudioSource(AudioRecordSource) from BiftorSettings
     * settings output format from BiftorSettings
     * make out dir from BiftorSettings
     * recorder.prepare() and set the recording state true
     * if recorder cant start put  recorder = null the user should select other recording Audio source
     * if recorder.start working fine set Isrecording=true else if recorder.start not wrok have problems 
     * set the Isrecording=false recording=false and set the recorder null
     * if Isrecording=true send notification and show toast start recording else recording failed
     */
    public void BiftorStartRecording()
    {       
    if(recording==false)
        {
        Boolean Isrecording;
   try {
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);   
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4); 
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        OutFile= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/BiftorRecorder"+"/BiftorCallRecorder";           

        File dir= new File(OutFile);
        if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();

        OutFormat = ".3gp";

        OutFile+="/"+CallNumber+ "_" + OutFileTime+ OutFormat;
        recorder.setOutputFile(OutFile);
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
            recording=true;
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            recorder = null;
            return;
        }
        recorder.start();
        Isrecording=true;

    } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        recording=false;
        Isrecording=false;
        recorder = null;
    }
   if(Isrecording){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.BiftorCallRecorder_Sarted) +CallNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }else
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.Recording) +getString(R.string.failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }   
}      

    /**
     * Stop Recording and check out file method
     * and send the BroadcastIntent
     * if recording have problem recording is false and put the recorder empty
     * relase,rest and stop the recorder at last put to null if recording is true
     */
    public void BiftorStopRecording()
        {
          if(recording==true)
             {
             if(recorder!=null){
              recorder.stop();
              recorder.reset();
              recorder.release();
              recorder=null;
              recording=false;
              SendBroadcastIntent();
              CheckOutPutFile(OutFile);
              }
             }
            else{
                recorder=null;
                recording=false;
                CheckOutPutFile(OutFile);
               }
            recorder =new MediaRecorder();                 
        }

    /**
     * Restart this service after end
     */
    public void SendBroadcastIntent()
        {
           Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.setAction("com.Biftor.BiftorCallRecorder.CALRECORDER_INTENT");
           sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

    /**
     * check output file if not having zero size save that
     */   
    public void CheckOutPutFile(String outfile)
    {
    File outputfile=new File(outfile);
    if (outputfile.exists()){
        if(outputfile.length()<=0){
            outputfile.delete();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.BiftorCallRecorder_Status)+" :"+
            getString(R.string.Recording)+" "+
            getString(R.string.is_empty), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.Record_Saved)+ OutFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }
    }

    }
```

**Edit 3**
added full service classes maybe need,also I got som new errors from android market about fix slash

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities.BiftorCallRecorder.t@4169cf60
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
at com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities.BiftorCallRecorder.BiftorCallRecorderService.a(Unknown Source)
at com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities.BiftorCallRecorder.BiftorCallRecorderService.b(Unknown Source)
at com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities.BiftorCallRecorder.t.onReceive(Unknown Source)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:788)
... 9 more
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

**[Edit]**
Move `MediaRecorder` creation code in `onReceive` method of `BiftorCallRecorderService`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    BiftorSettings();

    //Other stuffs here
}
```

**[Edit++]**
Add delay before `stop` in `BiftorStopRecording` method:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(15000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
recorder.stop();
recorder.reset();
recorder.release();
```

Comment: no stil not worked,just have delay after delay finished got me same error and FC

Comment: `IllegalStateException` is thrown when `stop` is called before `start`. Thats why this issue is intermittent. Please check if you are not calling `stop` before `start` in any case.

Comment: did't call stop before start,you can check added complete recording service in my question.

Comment: Try removing this check `if(!EnableCallRecording)return;` from `BiftorStartRecording()`

Comment: tried,same,are you sure the problem is about those things?
before i put the mediarecorder in onreceive the code working just in some times random got me error!

Comment: Yes. See the logs which you have given in comment. And this is what developer site says about the exception: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#stop()

Comment: ok how to fix???
i really need t fix this problem please help me,really need help for this case

Comment: Please clean your code and update the question. I will have a look. The code is not readable.

Comment: ok i will do it now,may i add your suggestions to new codes or wait?

Comment: Define one class variable that will be set when you call `recorder.start()`. Before calling `recorder.stop()`, check if that variable is set. Currently, you are doing this thing, but I guess the variable is not being set during `recorder.start()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not easy to read and there is a lot... so I'm not sure but it seems that the problem is the following :

In the `BiftorStartRecording` , if, for some reason, an exception occurs : you set `recorder = null;`  (look in the catch blocks of the `BiftorStartRecording` method).

Then, the `onReceive` is called (i.e. your broadcast receive a message) : under some  condition `BiftorStopRecording` is called from the `onReceive`.
`BiftorStopRecording` try to invoke something on the recorder, but the recorder is now null due to previous exception.

How to fix ?

- start by cleaning your code
- take care of the lifecycle of your recorder object (currently created when the service is instanciated, and set to null when an exception occurs : that's not good)

Hope it helps.

---

Try this :

```
public void BiftorStopRecording()
    {
    if(!EnableCallRecording)return;

        if(recording==true)
            {
            if(recorder!=null){ //add this check
               recorder.stop();
               recorder.reset();
               recorder.release();
               recorder=null;
            } //add this closing bracket too
            recording=false;
            SendBroadcastIntent();
            SendNotification(false);
            CheckOutPutFile(OutFile);
          } else {
              recorder=null;
              recording=false;
              SendNotification(false);
              CheckOutPutFile(OutFile);
          } 
          //prepare a new recorder for next call
          recorder = =new MediaRecorder();  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,yes codes is not small because i have many options,and i added all things in qustion if you can read codes please check and tell me where is the problem i really need to fix this random error,i set the recorder null because user after changed audio recorder source and the device not support,put the recorder null and reset and ready for other audio record source ,without this if user get error about audio source should do Reboot device to change that option

Comment: Where is the problem ? As I said in my post : the code is poorly written (so you need to clean it) and the lifecycle of the recorder object is problematic (so you have to focus on this after cleaning your code).

Comment: Honestly I don't see the difference: there is still commented useless code, auto-generated comments, many useless method regarding your problem. As I said before you must ensure that your recorder is never null when you receiver is invoked or don't try to use it if it is null. Really I don't know what to tell to help you more if on your side you don't try to follow my advices.

Comment: mate which useless method?all of them using i can not remove methods(functions),i checked code many time i cant fined useless method to remove can you the me which method for example??
about recorder null really i cant understand what you mean exactly"your recorder is never null when you receiver is invoked or don't try to use it if it is null"where is in codes i did it????can you show me and i can understand
really thanks mate.

Comment: i think problem is not about recording!is about receiving calls

Comment: I mean useless regarding your null recorder problem : find, BitforSetting(), ... (not useless for your app). Additionnaly there are many useless lines in other methods (make your code shorter : for instance a `return` is useless at last line of a void method... I hope you know that).

Comment: The problem is about receiving a call when your recorder is not ready... but I already told you that.

Comment: ok,i will remove other ,method now and just keep recording(BiftorStartRecording) and stop(BiftorStopRecording)
then the code is clean as well

Comment: i am trying your edit!need test!because that error was random.thank you

Comment: Hi mate,again same,what is your idea about add "if(recorder!=null)" at beginning of record?and prepare recorder again,:recorder =new MediaRecorder()" ?

Comment: tried to add both check at start recording "if(recorder!=null)" and "recorder =new MediaRecorder()" in the call onReceive(),but with new prepare mediarecorder in on recive i have error again!then just add check for if recorder was not null '                  if(find(Numbers_File, number) && RecordMyNumbersOnly&&recorder!=null)
                            BiftorStartRecording();
                  else if(!RecordMyNumbersOnly&&recorder!=null)
                   BiftorStartRecording();'
now all things seems is ok but need test with some calls,at last this check at beginning is true????

Comment: again i got some random error about it see the updated post updated codes :-(
Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x10 (has extras) }

Comment: where is BiftorCallRecorderService.java: line 282 ?

Comment: why line 282? is checkoutput method,in my codes not this cleaned,i was busy about exams if you try my app i think thats better https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Biftor.BiftorRecorderUtilities&hl=en

Comment: post updated edit added log from google play users about fix slash also added full last code